# Virtual machine as productive environment

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, productivity

So my father's small business is *stuck* with using Windows and they are really depending on it to run every day flawlessly. Occasionally that is not the case of course, be it because windows update blew up the system or something else needs immediate fixing. The biggest problem are however hardware faults and for that reason they keep a number of physically identical machines around. That way the drive with the operating system could be inserted there if anything happened to the hardware actively used.

This got me thinking now and I believe that a virtual machine would solve many of these problems. The productive system is easily backed up by copying the virtual disk. But best of all, the virtual OS could run on a variety of hosts, even if their hardware differs.

I thought of using **Ubuntu** as the host OS and **virtualbox** for virtualization. I would store the virtual disk on a local network server with the **ZFS** file system and back them up to external disks. Every employee would have his own virtual disk of course. **Ubuntu** because of improved security and especially because installing it to another machine and updating it takes around 15 minutes.

- Does anyone have experience in using virtual machines in a
  productive environment?
- Is there anything I should be aware of besides the reduced performance? They mainly need Windows because of Microsoft Access, so nothing CPU/GPU intensive. I'm asking here
  because changing all operating systems in a running business is not
  entirely risk free.
- Am I overlooking something?
- Should I consider
  other options than virtualbox?

Comment: Putting the disk onto a NAS will be really slow, so no. Besides a huge performance impact (except you have a really fast 10 GB network or so), things will be fine

Comment: @ThomasWeller Even with Gigabit ethernet and lots of memory on the host systems? Okay I could just as well store them locally and backup to the network location.

Comment: That would be my suggestion. We were using a Nutanix server for 25k€, but meanwhile, I'd say I had better bought a second machine for everyone... Well, let's see what answers you get. I'm interested in possible solutions

Comment: Okay local copies of the virtual disks it is then :)

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have experience in using virtual machines in a productive environment?

#### Amazon, goole, microsoft...most of the "cloud", most datacenters.

---

> Is there anything I should be aware of besides the reduced performance?
> They mainly need Windows because of Microsoft Access, so nothing CPU/GPU intensive.

#### I wouldn't be too concerned about reduced performance.

It is not significant if the hypervisor is set up properly, and I find Windows 7 runs better in a kvm environment than in a physical computer.  Personal opinion, depends on context.
To increase performance, install debian server instead.  Minimal server, add virtualisation and graphics only.

---

> Am I overlooking something?

#### - 1. You stated that hardware is the problem.

#### - 2. Why not use [access online](https://products.office.com/en-us/access)?  If your license is valid, is that not already functional?

#### - 3. Doubling the amount of os's adds a whole "company-wide os abstraction layer" of potential problems.  There is a support cost simply to maintain twice the amount of OS's even when everything is working well.

#### - 4. adding a very ram-intensive filesystem such as zfs is not the right solution to a hardware problem.  zfs is better to run on bsd or solaris anyways.  Perhaps [Btrsf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) is interesting if ext4 isn't for you.  Forget about zfs and windows compatibility also, as stated in the [FAQ](http://open-zfs.org/wiki/FAQ).

#### - 5. Doubling the amount of OS's simply because of a windows application licence does not add up to me.  A solution about the license, such as everyone having access without everyone having a complete working copy of windows just for access would be a solution.  Perhaps run virtualized slim versions of Windows instead, that only do access and employees can ssh in.   Or again, Microsoft access on office 360.

---

> I'm asking here because changing all operating systems in a running
> business is not entirely risk free.

#### Using virtualization software to support windows on bad hardware simply for Microsoft access is risky.

Maybe you can re-think the paradigm.  Does everyone need Microsoft access all the time?

---

> Should I consider other options than virtualbox?

#### Firstly look again at how much time per day each person needs access.

#### You could consider having a central windows interface where people log in for their access stuff.  How can people log in?  SSH with an X terminal for example.  Done with a desktop link.  Also, if you can centralize the whole access thing on a better computer, you won't be as susceptible to crashes as many computers in bad shape.  This can avoid issue with cache/lock files etc.

#### In a production environment, kvm or vmware would be more appropriate, but for desktops virtual box should be fine.

---

#### There is alot of enthusiasm and good ideas in the question.  There is much background work that was done.  Maybe try the question again without Microsoft access, then find a way to integrate Microsoft access.

Comment: It's not a hardware problem. It's that I need to remove the impact hardware problems can have on productivity. Regarding 2, the data is highly confidential, so any online solution is not an option. Regarding 4, I already have a Freenas server operating there, the memory is not an issue at all (16 GB for 4 TB of data, easily enough). Windows does not need to be compatible with ZFS either. First because the server supports samba shares and second because the host machine will use the Server, Windows itself will run from an image and does not even need to be aware of the server at all.

Comment: Regarding the rest, thanks for your input. I will think about it. But they pretty much need access all the time and that's the only reason why they cant move away from Windows. And I will dive into your idea with a centralized desktop.